# Number of weekend days in a month

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, nsdate

How I can get number of weekends in month or between two  NSDate ?
I was try do some tricks with

```
 calendar.components( NSCalendarUnit.WeekCalendarUnit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil)
```

But no result

Comment: Try to get the saturdays and sundays separately and then add those

Comment: maybe there is some more simple way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSInteger count = 0;
NSInteger saturday = 7;

// Set the incremental interval for each interaction.
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[oneDay setDay:1];

// Using a Gregorian calendar.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *currentDate = fromDate;

// Iterate from fromDate until toDate
while ([currentDate compare:toDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

    if (dateComponents.weekday == saturday) {
        count++;
    }

    // "Increment" currentDate by one day.
    currentDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay
                                            toDate:currentDate
                                           options:0];
}

NSLog(@"count = %d", count);
```

Comment: That's written in Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

According  TENSRI  I write code in swift with some fixs

```
func numberOfWeekdaysBeetweenDates(#startDate:NSDate,endDate:NSDate)->Int{
    var count = 0
    var oneDay = NSDateComponents()
    oneDay.day = 1;
    // Using a Gregorian calendar.
    var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    var currentDate = startDate;
    // Iterate from fromDate until toDate
    while (currentDate.compare(endDate) != .OrderedDescending) {

        var dateComponents = calendar.components(.WeekdayCalendarUnit, fromDate: currentDate)
        if (dateComponents.weekday == 1 || dateComponents.weekday == 7 ) {
            count++;
        }

        // "Increment" currentDate by one day.
        currentDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(oneDay, toDate: currentDate, options: nil)!
    }

    return count
}
```